# factory_girl: has many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have rich many to many relationship between projects and users. My project model has:

```
  has_many :project_members, dependent: :destroy, foreign_key: 'gallery_id'
  has_many :members, through: :project_members,
                     class_name: 'User',
                     foreign_key: 'member_id'
```

user model:

```
  has_many :project_members, dependent: :destroy, foreign_key: 'member_id'
  has_many :member_projects, through: :project_members,
                             source: :member_project
```

and project_member model:

```
  belongs_to :member_project, foreign_key: 'gallery_id', class_name: 'Project'
  belongs_to :member, foreign_key: 'member_id', class_name: 'User'
```

I wrote project factory as:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :project_member do
    association :project
    association :user
    role 'owner'
  end
end
```

However it gives me:

```
>  undefined method `project=' for #<ProjectMember:0x00000006f66048>
```

if I write following:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :project_member do
    association :member_project, foreign_key: 'gallery_id', class_name: 'Project'
    association :member, foreign_key: 'member_id', class_name: 'User'
    role 'owner'
  end
end
```

it says:

> Factory not registered: member_project

I am not sure how do I define many to many through factory object.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have factories for Project and User

```
factory :project_member do
    member_project FactoryGirl.build(:project)
    member FactoryGirl.build(:user)
    role 'owner'
end
```

Comment: You are close but not quite. I later found solution. Correct answer is: `association :member_project, factory: :project` and `association :member, factory: :user`

Comment: @sonalkr132 you should write this as an answer then